# Excel add year from Cell into existing formula

Tags: excel

I need to add the YEAR from a cell into an existing formula.

The formula works out the fiscal month & adds prefix 0 before the value.

```
="0"&MOD(MONTH(A2)-7,12)+1
```

I want the YEAR from Cell A to prefix the formula so the final value is

```
201507
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=YEAR(A1)&"0"&MOD(MONTH(A2)-7,12)+1

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add year to the beginning like `=YEAR(A2) &"0"&MOD(MONTH(A2)-7, 12)+1`?